# find the input is alphanumeric or not with using #define macro preprocessor in c

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, preprocessor, alphanumeric

this is the question what asked in my exam is: "write cource code of a character taken from user is alphanumeric or not."

alphanumeric means--> **A-Z** | **a-z** | **0-9** (alphabetic or numeric)
if it is return true or someting. help me to solve this question please..

in summary we will build **isalnum()** function ourselves.(with #define macros)

Comment: Google `man isalnum` - hey presto

Comment: using isalnum() function right ?

Comment: no. we need to define isalnum ourselves.(with using #define macro or macros, i don't know.)

Comment: Description and title doesn't match. I'm bit confused, can you edit the question @Sillyon ?

Comment: sorry for that @ThiruShetty. i will try

Comment: Sure, take the time to learn all you can about macros. It's a great educational endeavor. Then, a year from now, if you have continued to develop as a C programmer, revisit the wisdom of using macros for such purposes and see how much your desire to use them has changed.

Comment: This question is described as an exam question and was answered so fast that it could have actually been used in an exam. But you have not done so, have you? It is just your preparation for trying a second time to pass that exam, isn't it? Or maybe you passed that exam and just want to brush up on those questions you could not answer. This is probably an interesting read (for you and for those people who answered fast): https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the macro:

```
#define IS_ALNUM(x) (((x)>='a' && (x) <= 'z')) ||((x)>='A' && (x) <= 'Z')) || (((x)>='0' && (x) <= '9')))
```

It tests if it is

- Between a and z
- Between A and Z
- Between 0 and 9

Quite simple

Comment: sure, i used this as an example

Comment: Thanks for the fish. Make sure to have another fish ready for me tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

i solved this i think, thanks to all of you. that one is working:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define IS_LOWER(x)     ((x) <='z' && (x) >= 'a')  //then returns 1, else returns 0.
#define IS_UPPER(x)     ((x) <='Z' && (x) >= 'A')  //then returns 1, else returns 0.
#define IS_NUMERIC(x)   ((x) <= 9  && (x) >=  0 )  //then returns 1, else returns 0.

#define IS_ALPHANUM(x)  (IS_LOWER(x) || IS_UPPER(x) || IS_NUMERIC(x) ? (x) : (-1))
//then returns x, else returns -1.

int main()
{
    int a;
    a=IS_ALPHANUM('h'); //try h character one for example.
    printf("%d",a);
    return 0;
}
```

have a great coding days